# How do we define betweenness centrality when weights have a positive meaning?

Tags: graph, networkx, graph-theory, social-networking

I've read that betweenness centrality is defined as the number of times a vertex lies on the shortest path of the other pairs of nodes.

However, in case weights have a positive meaning (i.e. the more the weight of an edge the merrier), then how does one define betweenness centrality?

In this case, is there another way to calculate betweenness centrality? Or is it simply interpreted in a different way?

Comment: A wild guess would be using negative weights

Comment: @willcrack Wouldn't that cause trouble in case Dijkstra's algorithm is used for example? Would reciprocal weights work?

Comment: From [networkX documentation on betweenness centrality](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality)(see *Notes*), you can’t use negative edge weights...

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the centrality where you keep track of how many times a node is on the highest weighted path regardless of path length (number of edges)? If so, to get around the no negative edges in dijkstra's you could make new weights as `new_weight(i,j) = max(all_weights) - old_weight(i,j)`.

Comment: @cookesd In fact, I am just trying to understand how betweenness centrality is calculated/defined when all the weights of the graph are above 0 and higher weights are "better" than low weights (e.g. an edge is value of exports) and I can't grasp the idea of "shortest path" in this case. I am going to consider your implementation though!

Comment: @cookesd that looks like it would work

Comment: @Ethelom the new edge weights I described make the edges with the largest original weights now have the shortest new weight, so dijkstra's will want to utilize them to create a shortest path. Now that I think more about it though, it doesn't always choose the path with the largest original weight. For instance if `path a` has one edge with original weight 2 and `path b` has three edges, each with original weight 1, then with the new weights, dijkstra's will take `path a` yielding a weight of 2 when `path b` would ultimately yield the largest weight, but with more number of edges

Comment: @cookesd so, should betweenness centrality be calculated without necessarily taking weights into account?

Answer (score 3):

Computing the betweenness centrality of a vertex *v* relies on the following fraction, for any *u* and *w*: ***s(u,w,v) / s(u,w)*** where *s(u,w,v)* is the number of shortest paths between *u* and *w* that involve *v*, and *s(u,w)* is the total number of shortest paths between *u* and *w*.

With positive edge weights, **I would suggest that you count each shortest path with its own weight**: replace *s(u,w,v)*  by the sum of weights of shortest paths between *u* and *w* that involve *v*; and *s(u,w)* by the sum of weights of all shortest paths between *u* and *w*.

Then, **you have to define the weight of paths**, and this depends on what you have in mind. You may for instance consider the sum of edge weights, their product, their minimum or maximal value, etc.

Warning: this definition still relies on shortest *unweighted* paths; if longer paths with higher weights exist, they will be ignored, which means that graph structure prevails. This may not be satisfactory.

Note: this approach is somewhat equivalent, if edges have integer weight and a path weight is its edge weight product, to use the classical definition on a multi-graph (an unweighted graph where several edges may exist between two same vertices).